# These users are shown to have deduction in reputation but there are some mismatches

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, users

In this month's `Users` tab, at the last page, the following users are show to have deduction of reputation.
[image]

Some have offered bounties and have got downvotes, but certains users' profile doesn't show any activity of bounty or massive downvotes to their posts.

I then thought, may be they would have downvoted many posts and have got -1 rep for each downvote.

But this [user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152578/bevor?tab=topactivity) has voted only 11 times and all are upvotes.  They have not even offered bounty or have an active bounty.

Their reputation graph shows they have a rep. of **183** which matches with the up/downvotes, accepted posts and association bonus in their reputation tab.
[image]
[image]

But the block on the left shows a rep. of **83**, whereas the graph shows **183**.

These are not matching.

Similar action was found with this [user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/244695/machavity). They've voted only 26 times this month and not offered or have an active bounty.

Comment: That -100 is most likely 6 red flags (spam/rude/abusive) being raised on a post of them.

Comment: Maybe the bug for the Users page is new. I can't find one that explicitly mentions that effect.

Comment: Yeah Rene thanks! Got it!

Comment: There are plenty of other cases that reputation could be deducted. Consider that a user account who has voted on that other user's posts get deleted, for example.

Comment: Then there would be a notification showing "user was removed".. which is clearly not shown here @CodyGray

Comment: Could also be posts getting deleted.

Comment: @TylerH Yes, but the reputation earned through the posts available add up to **183** for Bevor (100 + 1 +9*10-4*2 = 183)